# Is the proof Proposition 2.8 of Bass's Book a necessary amount of complexity?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I was reading:

http://bass.math.uconn.edu/real.html

On page 13, we are given proposition 2.8 which lists 4 collections of sets

$$ \begin{matrix} C_1 = \lbrace (a,b) , a,b \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace  
 \\ C_2 =  \lbrace [a,b], a,b \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace \\ C_3 = \lbrace  (a,b],  a,b \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace \\ C_4 = \lbrace (a, \infty), a,b \in \mathbb{R}  \rbrace   \end{matrix} $$

And asked to show that the minimal sigma algebra generated by each of these sets is equal to the borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$.

My proof for $C_1$ matches bass's where we observe that every finite open interval is contained, and every infinite open interval can also be made by a countable union, and lastly, recalling proposition 1.5, every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals, so $\sigma(C_1)$ contains the borel algebra. Yet $C_1$ is a subset of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ so $\sigma(C_1)$ is also in the borel algebra and thus we have equivalency.

Here is where we differ in finishing the proof:

I observed the following:

If $u \in C, u \in \sigma(c)$ Furthermore: 
$$ u \in \sigma(c) \rightarrow u^c \in \sigma(c)$$ 
Since every sigma algebra being intersected to form $\sigma(c)$ is closed under complement. Similarly we have that if $u, v \in C, u \cup v \in \sigma(c), u \cap v \in \sigma(c)$

So to prove $C_2, C_3,C_4$ it suffices to show that every element of $C_1$ can be generated by each, and furthermore that every element of each can be generated by the borel algebra.  As an example in $C_2$ note that

$$ (b, c) = ([a,b]^c \cap [c,d]^c) \cap [e ,f], a < e < b < c < f < d \in \mathbb{R} $$

Thus $\sigma(C_2)$ generates $\sigma(C_1)$ and thus contains the Borel Algebra: But also

$$ [a,b] =  ((-\infty,a)\cup (b, \infty))^c , a < b \in \mathbb{R} $$

so The borel algebra contains $\sigma(C_2)$ and therefore they are equal.

This type of proof is much shorter than Bass's technique which talks about nested intervals so I'm a bit lost.

Am I missing something that's obviously wrong with my approach?

Comment: $$ (b, c) = ([a,b]^c \cup [c,d]^c) \cap [e ,f], a < e < b < c < f < d \in \mathbb{R} $$This isn't true.  Try $a=1,e=2,b=3,c=4,f=5,d=6.$  Sorry, I accidentally hit the enter key in the middle of my comment.

Comment: Which aspect is flawed?

Comment: Ah I made a mistake here that should be 2 intersections not just 1, let me update my post

Comment: @saulspatz its corrected :)

Comment: This looks correct to me now.  Slick argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a Comment. Let $S_0$ be the set of Borel sets. For $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ let $S_i$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by  $C_i.$ Here is how I would do it: $$S_0\supset S_2\supset S_3\supset S_4\supset S_1\supset S_0.$$ Proof:

(i). Members of $C_2$ are closed. So  $S_0\supset S_2.$

(ii). Any $c\in C_3$ is a countable union of members of $C_2$.  So $S_2\supset S_3.$

(iii). Any $c\in C_4$ is a countable union of members of $C_3$. So $S_3\supset S_4.$

(iv). Let $C'_4$ be the set of complements of members of $C_4.$ Any $(-\infty,b)$ is a countable union of members of $C'_4,$ while  $(a,\infty)\in C_4$. So $(a,b)=(-\infty,b)\cap (a,\infty)\in S_4.$ So $S_4\supset S_1.$

(v). Any open set $c$ is a countable union of members of $S_1$ because $c=\cup \{(a,b): a,b\in \Bbb Q\land (a,b)\subset c\}$ . So $S_1\supset S_0.$

Footnote. For (ii) we have $(a,b]=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}[a+n^{-1},b].$ The  countable unions in (iii) and (iv) are handled similarly.